# Casting a const int to a pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, casting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Modifying a const through a non-const pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2508605/modifying-a-const-through-a-non-const-pointer)

I have the following code:

```
const int x = 5;
int *p = (int*)&x;

*p = 2; // Line 1

cout << x << " - " << *p << endl;
cout << &x << " - " << p << endl;
```

And got the results:

```
5 - 2
0012FF28 - 0012FF28
```

I know the code is weird and should never do it. But I wondered why the same address but got different result? And where the `Line 1` store the number 2?

Comment: Ask your compiler to generate an assembly listing and find out. Probably what happens, is your compiler reckons `x` is `const` (rightly so) and therefore compiles the value inline into your first `cout` statement.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because changing the value of an inherently `const` variable in anyway is **Undefined Behavior**<sup>[Ref #1]</sup>.

Once you did:

```
*p = 2; // Line 1
```

All bets are off, and your code is no longer a valid C++ code, You cannot expect any particular behavior once that line was written. To speculate why an Undefined Behavior gives any particular behavior is pointless because it is allowed to show *any* behavior<sup>[Ref #2]</sup> that is the meaning of *Undefined Behavior*.

---

<sup>[Ref #1]</sup>
**C++03 Standard 7.1.5.1 The cv-qualifiers:**
**Para 4:**

> Except that any class member declared mutable (7.1.1) can be modified, any attempt to modify a const object during its lifetime (3.8) results in undefined behavior.

<sup>[Ref #2]</sup>
**C++03 Standard 1.3.24:**

> Permissible undefined behavior ranges from ignoring the situation completely with unpredictable results, to behaving during translation or program execution in a documented manner characteristic of the environment (with or without the issuance of a diagnostic message), to terminating a translation or execution (with the issuance of a diagnostic message).

Comment: I read the section in the document you referenced, the document mentioned about cv-qualifiers. what are cv-qualifiers? (They also stated there are 2 cv-qualifiers: const and volatile)

Comment: @ipkiss: cv(*const-volatile*)-qualifiers are *(data)type* qualifiers they specify additional attributes like constness and volatility to (data)type objects.

Answer (score 1):

Declaring something `const` gives the compiler permission to assume that that value will not change.  This means that they can use an "immediate" instruction to load the value `5`, rather than referencing the location (if any) assigned to `x`.

Further, modifying a `const` violates the assurance you gave the compiler that that "variable" would not be modified, and could produce a variety of unanticipated behaviors.

Answer (score 1):

while some compilers do allocate an address for const values, it is a big no-no to access it. the reason you get 5-2 is because the compiler is replacing x directly with 5, even though you modified the address where x would have been given an address if it were not const and unless you access x's value through p* you are going to get 5 every time no matter what you do - also, p* may yield an undefined value since the getting the address of a const may actually fail with some compilers (and i think it should with all of them, personally)