# pointer to a const int and modify its value via pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, constants

I am learning pointers and got confused when I tried to modify the value of a const int through its address. I am not sure if it has any practical meaning. I just want to learn how the pointer works for const int. Here is the code:

```
const int a = 10;
*((int*)&a) = 20;
cout << a << endl;
cout << *(&a) << endl;
```

It prints 10 and 20. But I thought it should print 20 and 20, because in the second line, I casted &a and modified its value. So the value of a should change, because the bit pattern at that address changed.

I also tried the following code:

```
int a = 10;
*((int*)&a) = 20;
cout << a << endl;
cout << *(&a) << endl;
```

It prints 20 and 20 as I expected. I just don't understand how does const works in this case. I really appreciate it if anyone could give any suggestions.

Comment: `const int a = 10; *((int*)&a) = 20;` is undefined behavior in C.  The rest is moot.

Comment: `cout << a << endl;` is not valid C.  Perhaps you are coding in another language like C++?

Comment: thanks for your reply! could you please give more details on this undefined behavior? And why it works as expected if const is removed as in the second scenario? Thanks!

Comment: It prints the same result if I change cout << a << endl; to printf("%d\n", a);

Comment: @user3204065 Certainly the  [dupe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2508605/modifying-a-const-through-a-non-const-pointer) explains it.